# Are Cosets Isomorphic to One Another

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

A basic question, I seem to be struggling with the concept of quotient groups and cosets.

Suppose $G$ is a group, and $N$ is a normal subgroup.

I know that is $x$ and $y$ are in the same coset of $G/N$, then $xN = yN$.

I also know that cosets are either disjoint or equivalent,  $G/N$ is the set of cosets. Also, $G$ can be written as a disjoint union of the cosets.

> Is it correct that all cosets are isomorphic to $N$, since they are of the form $xN$ for some $x \in G$?
>
> Or is it possible for more elements of $G$ to be in one coset than in another?

Comment: What does it mean for cosets to be isomorphic? In any case all cosets have the same cardinality.

Comment: Can't sets be isormophic? At least I think I have head the term "set isomorphism"

Comment: A "set isomorphism" is simply a bijection, @Jess.

Comment: $G/N$ is the _set_ of cosets, not their disjoint union. That union is $G$ itself.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks for correcting that! I edited the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct arguing that cosets are equicardinal (the same size), since for fixed $x$ the map $n \to xn$ is a bijection.

Your mistake (pointed out in comments and the other answer) is saying that makes them isomorphic. They can't be, since only $N$ itself is a group. When you are studying group theory, "isomorphic" means "isomorphic as groups".

In general, isomorphisms preserve the structure of the objects you are studying. When you are studying sets, an isomorphism is just a bijection, since sets have no other structure. So the map $n \to xn$ is indeed a set isomorphism.

Answer (score 5):

A coset $xN$ of $N\unlhd G$ for nontrivial $x$ cannot be isomorphic to $N$ if $xN\neq N$, since $xN$ has no identity element (why?) and is thus not a group.

There is, however, a bijection $\varphi:N\to xN$ given by $n\mapsto xn$. So the sets are of the same cardinality.

Comment: I have thought through why $xN$ doesn't contain the identity, but can't sets be isomorphic?

Comment: They can be a bijection between sets, yes, @Jess; I have amended my answer now. Please don't forget to upvote & accept an answer!

Comment: *There ${}{}{}$

Comment: Since I accepted the other answer and I've seen you a lot with my abstract algebra questions, I feel like I should also say your edits and replies are always appreciated!

Comment: Why, thank you, @Jess. What a lovely sentiment!